# How to display lyrics of songs?

Tags: music-player, lyrics

When I was using Windows, I had an application called [MiniLyrics](http://www.crintsoft.com/) which let me display the lyrics of the music files played. The application automatically downloads the lyrics and displays them while the song plays. Is there a similar application in Ubuntu that I could use?

Comment: Most music players are able to download an display lyrics either per default or throug a plugin. How to set this up depends on the player used. Which player are you using?

Comment: I usually use Banshee or VLC. Seems like OSDLyrics works with a very limited number of music players. Good thing is it works well with all of my music players (Clementine, Rhythmbox, VLC and Banshee). :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is also a screenlet lyrics (works great with Banshee), all you need to do is to install [Screenlets](http://screenlets.org/index.php/Home)(widget applications):

**Note**: [Installing software from PPA may pose a security risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

And then add Lyrics widget to the desktop.

[image]

Comment: Tell me, please, are there other settings?  - -installed screenlets and lyrics but all I get is a volume sign with a question mark. Does it work with xfce desktop?

Comment: It does not work for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N5R1b.png :(

Comment: This looks rad !

Answer (score 16):

After a bit of Google researching, I ended up with [this article on OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/display-song-lyrics-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/). The OSD-Lyrics they suggested works like the way Minilyrics used to work. So, I am delighted.

[OSDLyrics](http://code.google.com/p/osd-lyrics/) can be installed by the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osd-lyrics/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install osdlyrics
```

Comment: This PPA does not work on 13.10 => http://askubuntu.com/questions/207073/lyric-player-just-like-miniyrics-in-ubuntu-12-10-with-highlighted-scrolling-lyri#comment572190_207146 | Also; It does not work properly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lyrics

Comment: Note that on more recent versions of Ubuntu it's in the default repositories: `sudo apt install osdlyrics python3-pycurl` (tested on 23.04)

Answer (score 11):

Why have a separate app for lyrics and not have them within the player? Maybe the external app like osdlyrics has a larger database? In fact it is far from matching Clementine's or that of Foobar2000 addons like Lyric Show Panel 3.

Clementine:

[image: clementine with lyrics]

Foobar2000 in Wine/Playonlinux (excellent access to synced lyrics  option to save them in tags etc):

[image: Foobar2000 in Wine with lyrics]

DeaDBeeF:

[image]

I trust there are other good players to be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

### **Audacious**

---

The plugin that has to be stated is called LyricWiki.

***Audacious GTK***, in Settings>Plugins:

[image]

Lyrics are shown in a separate window:

[image]

The above is the GTK UI, but that window looks the same with the ***classic Winamp-like interface***:

[image]

Once closed, that window needs to be enabled by selecting the plugin again as above.

The same is true for ***Audacious Qt interface***, but there the lyrics window can be integrated within the main one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the Qt UI we can increase fonts by scrolling while holding CTRL.

---

---

### Qmmp

---

Similarly, the plugin needs to be enabled: Edit>Settings>Plugins>General

[image]

Then, select track in playlist and press CTRL-L, or: right click, Actions. Sadly, this has to be done for each track, as the lyrics window keep showing the first ones.

[image]

It seems the plugin searches before opening the window. No window opened means no lyrics available.

To increase fonts, scroll while holding CTRL.

Answer (score 0):

On 14.04, if you are using Banshee, you can check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/469903/46437), as the lyrics plugin seems still broken to the date.

The script found there is simple and I believe it can be easily updated to work with other music players.

Answer (score 0):

The following lyrics packages can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (12.04/14.04/16.04/16.10/17.04/17.10/18.04).

- banshee-extension-lyrics - lyrics extension for Banshee Media Player
- ncmpc-lyrics - ncurses-based audio player (lyrics plugins)
- clementine - If Clementine music player can identify a song, lyrics can be displayed in the information panel. This is built into Clementine without the need for any plugin.