# Possible to change Banshee's Lyric source

Tags: 11.10, banshee, lyrics

I discovered yesterday that Banshee (through Ubuntu Software Center) had an extension for Lyrics and I immediately installed it. It was awesome to read and sing my favorite songs but then everything went down when **Journey's - Don't Stop believing** had no Lyric. In my world this is unacceptable. I mean come on is Journey. That is like McDonalds not selling burgers anymore. So before I quit Banshee because it is breaking law #47 of Music players which states "Music Players must have lyric for Journey's - Don't Stop believing else smite down on it to oblivion" I want to know:

How can I change the source to grab Lyrics in Banshee. Is there a possibility to change the url or site where it grabs the lyrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the extension your are currently using is banshee-extension-lyrics, changing the lyric sources requires a code change.
Banshee-extension-lyrics searches four sites; but only one of those is still live (lyricwiki.org - which redirects to lyric.wikia.org). That site appears to have the lyrics you want if you perform a manual search, but it seems that banshee-extension-lyrics isn't smart enough to find them because the track title doesn't exactly match (actual title given is Don't stop believin').

There are other lyric options for banshee that may work better for you - [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75371/how-to-display-lyrics-of-songs) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing that source code, you can try this script [secLyricsForBanshee.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secLyricsForBanshee.sh), it has support for one site, but it can be changed to support more sites.

It detects banshee and shows the current playing music lyrics. It could detect other music players also just need that to be coded there.