# Lyric player just like Miniyrics in ubuntu 12.10 with highlighted scrolling lyrics

Tags: 12.10, music, lyrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display lyrics of songs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75371/how-to-display-lyrics-of-songs)

I have been adjusting to ubuntu 12.10 and it seems to be no trouble so far(except a few glitches).
I have been searching for a lyrics player like Minilyrics.
It serves as an add-on to Winamp.
But i cant find one just like it :-(
I have tried Clementine & rhythmbox, but they don't satisfy those needs.
Amrok has scrolling lyrics, but it doesn't have highlighted lyrics and is sometimes out of Sync.
These are the things are that I believe that give Windows & Mac the upper hand........

Answer (score 1):

[OSDLyrics](https://code.google.com/p/osd-lyrics/) is lyric player similar to Minilyrics ,displays lyrics with many mediaplayers including Banshee and Rhythmbox.

to install with ppa from Ubuntu try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osd-lyrics/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install osdlyrics
```

Comment: Dude its coming :Unable to locate package

Comment: @harsh, `wget https://osd-lyrics.googlecode.com/files/osdlyrics_0.4.3-1~precise1_amd64.deb` then install the deb file by gdebi.